# Spontaneous Unterminated String Literal Error when trying to include external OpenLayers Javascript file in html

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, openlayers

I get an odd unterminated string literal error when opening my website on my Laptop at home. If I try to open the website at work (where I programed it), the error does not appear. First I started to compare the Firefox versions, but both are the same -> 19.0.

After trying some "Unterminated String Literal"-Error Fixes, like they are described in many threads here on the stackoverflow site, I got more errors in the external js file. So I thought I have an error in the inclusion of this file and tried different possibilities of inclusions (f.e. with and without adding type="javascript" in the script tag). After a few vain tries, I decided to put it back to its previous state:

```
<script src="js/openLayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

The error that is still appearing says

```
"SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" in string 
"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAQAIBRAA7"
in OpenLayers.js on line 48.
```

So I tried to put the whole OpenLayers.js in my html as internal Javascript and everything worked fine.

**Has anyone an idea why this error is only occuring when the OpenLayers.js is included as external js?**

Comment: At home you may have a browser plugin causing this issue. Have you tried with a self-closing `<script ... />` tag ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried a self-closing tag and also tried to start firefox in save mode.

And yes, it is also working in IE at home :)

Comment: Where is your external js hosted ?

Comment: I have a root folder, where my html (or better saying .php) file is located. From there the js file is located in the folder /js/openLayers/ . The server that I'm using is a Map Server for Windows provided from work.

Edit: I am also using other external js files that are working well.